# Create Slash Command for a Discord Bot and Have It Connect to a Voice Channel to Play an Audio File

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Me and my friend want to make another Discord bot that, when a user uses `/playmusic`, the bot joins a specified voice channel and plays an audio file in it.

I would search this in the discord.py docs, but I don’t understand them.

Here is the code I have so far, it obviously doesn’t work (see traceback below):

```
import os, re, discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import ffmpeg
import asyncio

DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.tree.sync()
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("message was: " + message.content)
    msg = message.content
    lowered = msg.lower()
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if lowered == 'i love baguettes!' or lowered == 'i love baguettes':
        role = message.guild.get_role(1085983212855115887)
        await message.author.add_roles(role, reason="You said the magic words!", atomic=True)
        await message.channel.send('So do I! In fact, I have given you the Baguette Team role!')

@client.tree.command(name="kill", description="Kills Blockcoin Bot.")
async def _space(ctx: discord.interactions.Interaction):
    await ctx.response.send_message(content="How dare you try to kill me!")

    
@client.tree.command(name="give-lollipop", description="Gives Blockcoin Bot a lollipop.")
async def _space(ctx: discord.interactions.Interaction):
    await ctx.response.send_message(content="Thank you for the lollipop!")


@client.tree.command(name="playmusic", description="Starts playing music in the music channel.")
async def _space(ctx: discord.interactions.Interaction):
    voice_channel = ctx.response.author.voice.channel
    voice_client = await voice_channel.connect()
    source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('sample-15s.mp3'))
    voice_client.play(source)
    while voice_client.is_playing():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await voice_client.disconnect()

def start():
    client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

**Traceback**

```
  raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e discord.app_commands.errors.CommandlnvokeError: Command 'playmusic' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'InteractionResponse' object has no attribute 'author'
```

Comment: "...it obviously doesn’t work..." Then what does the code do? Do you get an error message? Does the other commands that doesn't connect to a channel work? We need more debugging-details to effectively answer this question.

Comment: Please see the help-page [MRE]